# Why am I getting Timeout error in the assertion step

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I first tried this

```
let url = await pa.getPageURL("Employees");
    console.log("URL "+url);
```

Then I tried this. Both are throwing time out error but printing the correct url.

```
it('should be able to open Employees page',async () => {
    loginPg.login();
    pa.getPageURL("Employees").then(function(url){
    console.log("URL "+url);
    expect(url).toContain("employees");
})
})

async getPageURL(pageName){
    this.menu.click()
    let url = element(by.xpath('//span[contains(.,"'+pageName+'")]')).click().then(function(){
            return browser.getCurrentUrl();
        })
        return url;
}
```

I'm writing a test where it clicks on a page link from the menu and assert the url. It works fine and click the link and goes to the correct page.
I have also verified that the console.log is correctly printing the url in the above code. But it fails everytime with Timeout error.

- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)

What am I missing here? All my other tests work fine. Please help!

Comment: Can you add getPageUrl() method here? Does you this method resolves a promise?

Comment: async getPageURL(pageName){
    this.menu.click()
    let url = element(by.xpath('//span[contains(.,"'+pageName+'")]')).click().then(function(){
            return browser.getCurrentUrl();
        })
        return url;
}

Comment: updated description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a return keyword before your expect.

And also make sure to check DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL it will be 5 secs by default. Try changing it to 10 secs. So,That time is sufficient for logging in and then proceeding with actual expect.

Comment: increasing the defaultTimeoutInterval fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please have default timeout to be 30 or 60 sec

Comment: ok earlier I had the timout interval as 10000, now increased it to 40000 and it works now. What is a reasonable timeout interval?

Comment: 60 seconds should be fine